# Spring mvc request mapping returns Http Status 404 instead of String

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST service based on Spring MVC. I have defined a method to support GET as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/resource/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getResource(@PathVariable int id) {
        System.out.println("GET Resources for Project ID: "+id);

        ResponseV responseV=new ResponseV();
        DataVO data=new DataVO();
        allResources=resourceServiceImpl.getResource(id);
        data.setPeopleList(allResources);
        responseV.setData(data);

        XStream xstream = new XStream();       
        xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
        String output_getRes = xstream.toXML(responseV);
        System.out.println(output_getRes);
        return output_getRes;
    }
```

The service should return string when i place an url like: `http://localhost:8077/proj/service/resource/0` .. But it gives a 404 status error. the ouptut is retruned properly in the console but i get 404 in browser window.. any help ?

Comment: What exactly do you run in the console?

Comment: no no.. i dont run in the console.. i run it using a url like: http://localhost:8077/proj/service/resource/0 .. it accesses my webservice and returns me the output as string.. i get the 404 status in my browser window.. but as i have done syso i get the correct out in console.. please tell how can i get the same output in the browser window too

Comment: I'm sorry but you really didn't explain yourself. You said you run it in console and now you say that it isn't from the console. So, how do you run it? Is it from the IDE?

Comment: i specified it twice.. its a web application.. i run it on a server.. tomcat.. in eclipse ide..

Comment: I guess you understand yourself :) But I really am trying to help you here. Code 404 means that the url refers to a page that doesn't exist.
You say that the **output returned properly in the console**. Which console? What do you mean by this line?
What I'm trying to understand here is if the url is correct or not. Because the immediate suspect is some sort of spelling mistake in the url unless you tell me that you ruled that out.

Answer (score 0):

you get 404 error ,one reason when no mapping found for your http request. but you said request reaches your servlet and not getting the response back. i would suggest first to check your viewresolver redirects to your desired page,(in this case you would get different exception  http 500 error (cant resolve the view) and not http 404 error !!), secondly check whether your request getting resolved or not